# Pure logic: how to get number of shares, knowing part and price of the share

Tags: logic

My question is not about programming languages but definetly about programming.

I have a model portfolio with shares:

```
Part        Code        Price, $    Number of shares in portfolio
23,80%      CSIQ        24,91           ?
18,90%      TSL         10,52           ?
11,20%      JKS         24,40           ?
10,70%      YGE         2,90            ?
35,40%      DQ          26,05           ?
```

I need to calculate minimum number of shares that should be in portfolio so that part of that share in portfolio would equal to part in model portfolio.

Just imagine that you want to purchase such portfolio in real world. **How many of each stocks should you buy, to get desired part** (which is shown in model portfolio). I can't buy non-integer number of shares and part in recalculated (after purchase) portfolio should equal part in model portfolio.

Example: I need to get portfolio with 50.0% in Google ($500 per share) and 50.0% in Apple ($700 per share). Solution is 5 shares of Apple (total value $3500) and 7 shares of Google (total value $3500).

Answer (score 0):

Let us expand on the approach devised in the comments.

The first step is to choose a share to be a reference point; this can be any, so we'll go with the first one, CSIQ. Let us say then that we will purchase one share of this, so we now know that 23.8% of the portfolio is worth $24.91.

For the second share, this is now the problem we have:

```
Part        Code        Price, $    Number of shares in portfolio
23,80%      CSIQ        24,91           1
18,90%      TSL         10,52           ?
```

Since we know the value of a fraction of the portfolio, let us work out what the whole portfolio would be:

```
total_value = (100 / 23.8) * 24.91
            = $104.663865546
```

That means the amount we can spend on TSL is:

```
tsl_value   = 104.663865546 * (18.8/100)
            = $19.676806723
```

We know how much a TSL share costs, so we must buy a non-integer amount of this share:

```
share_amount = 19.676806723/10.52
             = 1.87041908
```

You can then go through each share in the same way, and end up with a portfolio in the desired ratios.

If you already own a number of shares in one stock, you can modify the algorithm but instead of starting with 1 share, you start with X shares - multiply everything by X and it will still work.

---

After you added the constraint that shares can only be purchased in integer amounts, I would suggest that you use the X multiplier approach above, coupled with rounding share amounts to the closest integer. As you increase X exponentially (10, 100, etc) your level of inaccuracy due to rounding will get progressively smaller.

As I suggested in the comments, you could build this in a spreadsheet first and determine the level of inaccuracy for inputs of X. Of course, if you plan to actually buy these shares, X is constrained by the amount of money you have; conversely if it is theoretical you can make it 6 or 7 figures and achieve good levels of accuracy.